# python: "sys.path.append" not taking parameter

Tags: python, import, module, directory, sys

I'm trying to find a way to import a module automatically in my script if the directory of the module is in the same directory of the script. Here is the code:

```
import sys
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()
dirs= os.listdir(cwd)

for dirName in dirs:
    if dirName == "arrayUtilities":
        modulePath =  str(cwd) +"/" + str(dirName)
        sys.path.append(modulePath)

import arrayUtilities as arr
```

The script is in a directory where there is also the module's directory and it should work. Any help?

Comment: you should not use `cwd = os.getcwd()` but `cwd = os.path.dirname(__file__)` as the current dir may not be the one you're expecting.

Comment: I'm not sure of the point of the for loop. If you know the dir name you want to add, why not do so directly?

Comment: To elaborate on @Jean-FrançoisFabre's comment: `os.getcwd()` will give you the directory that the script is *executed from*, whereas `os.path.dirname(__file__)` will give you the directory that the script is *located in* (which is what you want).

Comment: @DanielRoseman I do this to check if the user created the program in module's directory

Comment: I figured it out, i didn't understand how sys.path worked, now i know that what i wanted to do was useless